# Is there any way to restore promoted results once deleted?

Tags: 2013, search, restore, promoted-results

We had a Search configuration built in SharePoint 2013 with many promoted results for our pages.

However after having some issues and having to delete and recreate our entire Search Service Application with fresh databases, we lost all our promoted results (among other aspects to our search but these are the hardest to restore).

With database backups of our entire search topology, is there any way to get these promoted results back?

Comment: Did you create then in the SSA or the site collection?

Comment: In the SSA itself via Central Admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a SSA in a test environment and restore the backups of the SSA databases. Then write some PowerShell to dump the configuration. That is the only way I can think to do it.